# prevent youtube playing the video automatically

Tags: youtube, flash, multimedia

one thing that annoys me on [youtube](http://youtube.com) is that it always starts playing the video automatically after opening the video page.

is there a way how to prevent it? i don't see such option in profile settings.

Comment: Closers: superuser.com does not permit questions about web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/) firefox extention. That will prevent anything flash from starting automatically. This works perfectly on youtube, and as a bonus it will get rid of a huge amount of annoying ads with blinking text or whatnot.

Comment: You can also try TubeStop Firefox Extension http://www.chrisfinke.com/addons/tubestop/

Answer (score 4):

There plenty of [greasemonkey scripts](http://userscripts.org) available to do this exact thing (search for 'autoplay').  Also, this belongs on Super User.

Comment: I use greasemonkey.  That plugin is the shit.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/

Comment: I'd say it actually belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ but you can't vote for that!